# How can I find how nutch reached a link/url?

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

We have an odd situation with a Nutch crawl we're doing, wherein at some point Nutch reaches an erroneous webpage for which, really, the server should be sending a 404. For whatever reason the server isn't.

When Nutch hits this "bad" URL, a page generates with all relative paths based off an erroneous. So, if the root page is "http://example.com/bad", this page will have hundreds of links for things like "example.com/bad/data/1" and "example.com/bad/calendar/2012" and "example.com/bad/data/1/calendar/2012".

As such, Nutch will continue to crawl forever.

I'd like to trace back whatever page erroneously first links to this "bad" page. It seems like this should maybe be possible using either the `bin/nutch readlinkdb` or the `bin/nutch readdb` command. I have tried specifying an error url (via '--url') with each with no relevant URLs found. Doing a full dump does in fact net data that doesn't include any erroneous URLs. But Nutch definitely does inject erroneous URLs into Solr.

Why would this be, and how can I trace Nutch's path to the erroneous URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to solve this problem:

1. Setting the `linkdb.ignore.internal.links` property to `false`. This will populate all inlinks to each URL and you can find the bad link manually from the `readlinkdb` dump.
2. Setting the `linkdb.max.inlinks` property in `nutch-default.xml` to 1. This will only store the first URL that linked to the page in the `linkdb`. You will still need to set `linkdb.ignore.internal.links` property to `false`.